# Facebook.GetTaskAsync giving [net_unknown_prefix] error

Tags: silverlight, facebook, silverlight-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using Facebook API v5.3 BETA, although have tried the following using v5.2.1 Stable. I am also using the Facebook.Extensions.Tasks library. Upon calling the FBClient.GetTaskAsync() function I get the [net_unknown_prefix] error, any ideas?

```
public string GetFacebookMe(string access_token)
    {
        FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(access_token);
        string _Response = "";
        var task = fb.GetTaskAsync("/me");

        task.ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                if (t.Exception == null)
                {
                    dynamic result = t.Result;
                    _Response = result.name;
                }
                else
                {
                    _Response = "Error";
                }
            });

        return _Response;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have the Async CTP SP1 installed inorder to use the Facebook.Extensions.Task library.

Starting from v5.3 beta XTaskAsync methods are already part of the core Facebook.dll. Although for now it is available only for .net 4.0 and .net 4.5.

You can read more about it at [http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-What’s-new-in-v5-3.aspx](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-What%E2%80%99s-new-in-v5-3.aspx)